# Using both whipped egg whites and egg yolks vs whipped egg whites only?

Tags: baking, leavening

Would you get more leavening if you used both whipped egg whites and egg yolks and folded them into a batter (pancake batter,for example)compared to using whipped egg whites only, and would it make a noticeable difference? If yes, then why is it more common to use just the whites?

Comment: It's no extra benefit, which is why recipes don't call for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you substitute whole eggs for egg whites in baking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14214/can-you-substitute-whole-eggs-for-egg-whites-in-baking)

Answer (score 3):

Whipping egg whites is usually done to make a batter lighter and fluffier. In such a case, adding in egg yolks will likely make the batter denser and less fluffy.

On the other hand, if the recipe has substituted  egg white for egg in order to make a recipe healthier by reducing fat content, you can revert to using whole eggs (1 for every 2 egg whites). The texture will still be different, but that might be what you want.

Comment: Even if they're whipped?  I would have thought that whipping the yolks,  just like when whipping whites, would aerate them so it would provide more leavening?

Comment: No. Even a little bit off egg yolk in your egg white will prevent fluffy meringue formation.

Comment: I mean whipping them seperately. So e.g. you would fold in the whipped egg yolks into the batter first (as the 2nd to last ingredient in the batter), and then the whipped egg whites last.

Comment: That would allow the whites to whip and it would add some air, but the fat in the egg yolks will still make your food denser. This might be what you want (eg. fudgy brownies aren't supposed to be light and fluffy).