# How can I make better eggless scones?

Tags: substitutions, eggs, chocolate, cream, vegan

I made chocolate scones using [this recipe](http://www.joyofbaking.com/ChocolateScones.html), using the milk/cream but leaving out the eggs because I'm vegan. The scones didn't come out soft. What might be the reason? Is there any substitute for the eggs that can make the scones softer?

Comment: See this question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14025/are-there-any-vegetarian-friendly-egg-substitutes-that-can-be-used-in-cakes