# Eggless Belgian Waffles become unbreakably hard

Tags: waffle

I am a big admirer of Belgian Waffles and hence have been trying to come up with the perfect recipe to prepare them. However, I cannot use eggs in waffles because majority of my cousins are vegetarian.

My Recipe:

```
389 gms All Purpose Flour
5 gms salt
12 gms baking powder
14 gms sugar
500 gms milk
50 gms oil
111 gms cornstarch
Vanilla Essence
```

I took this recipe from a website and later replaced eggs with 2 tbsp flour & water, 0.5 tbsp of butter and baking powder.

The only problem seems to be hardness. Using this recipe, I get crispy waffles but within 2 minutes, one cannot break the waffles because it turns chewy like rubber. I keep my wafflemaker at 200 degrees for 5 minutes. Waffles are quite crisp but not airy I suppose and one cannot break the waffles apart just after 2 minutes.

I would be glad if you may help me out in any way to prepare Eggless Belgian waffles.

Comment: That's a **LOT** of cornstarch! I just replace eggs and oil in a normal recipe with yogurt, and get an edible result.

Comment: Check with your cousins: if they are vegetarian they will probably eat eggs. Maybe you meant they are vegan?

Answer (score 5):

Flour, water, butter, and baking powder does not sound like a great egg substitute to me.

Your best option is to just go find a [vegan belgian waffle recipe](https://www.google.com/search?&q=vegan%20belgian%20waffle%20recipe&oq=vegan%20belgian&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.3068j0j). There are tons of them, and they should be much more reliable than trying to modify an existing recipe.

If you're really set on modifying that one recipe, look for a better egg substitute. There are products specifically designed to act as one, as well as [a fair number of other things](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/14025/1672) that will likely work better than what you tried. The problem is, different ones work better in different contexts, and it can take some tweaking to get recipes to work right.