# Substitute of eggs

Tags: baking, vegan

I am a vegan and love to bake cakes. But every cake recipe requires egg which I don't want to use. So can anybody tell me what should I use in replacement of eggs without affecting the results?

Comment: Welcome to the site @Dev. The question you are asking already has an answer: [Are there any vegetarian-friendly egg substitutes that can be used in cakes?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14025/are-there-any-vegetarian-friendly-egg-substitutes-that-can-be-used-in-cakes)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you like experimenting, I suggest that you simply use recipes for vegan cakes. Eggs are a versatile ingredient with many purposes, and there is no 1:1 vegan egg replacement that covers all of these uses.

If you're Swedish I warmly recommend the books and facebook page of Karolina Tegelaar, in particular [her cake book](http://shop.djurensratt.se/product/t%C3%A5rtor). If not there are plenty of other vegan cake books available in english, such as [Have Your Cake and Vegan Too](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1569759200).

When you've tried some of these recipes, you'll get a feeling for what substitutes work for which purposes and can begin to recombine, experiment and innovate :)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you look for an vegan egg substitute in a health food store or the vegan section of your local or favorite grocery store. Good Luck!!